# multiple file upload symfony 2

Tags: symfony

How to use multiple files upload in symfony? I'm not really
sure how to do it 'the symfony way'. I read [How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), but how upload many files?

I try use [collection field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and add setFiles method to object model

> ```
> public function setFiles($files)
> {
>     $this->files = $files;
>     foreach ($files as $file) {
>         $file->setObject($this);
>     }
> }
> ```

but have exception (this always worked for normal model without any files)

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::setObject()

please help me.

UPDATED:
I use for main object second form with file, and...

> ```
>       $files = $this->getRequest()->files->get('val_image');
>       foreach($files as $file){
>             $foto = new Foto;
>             $foto->setFile($file);
>             $foto->setPremises($premises->getPremises());
>             $this->getEm()->persist($foto);
>         }
> ```

it's works :)

Comment: i dont understend you :( example?

Comment: I mean try something like this `/**
  * @Assert\All({
  *     @Assert\File
  * })
  */private $files;
` and just do `$this-> files = $files`

Comment: Create for file a spearate entity and then attach it like a one to many relation. e.g MyEntity has a field $photos, and this is collections of a FileEntity. I can give you a bigger example if you need

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin can help you:

https://github.com/caoimhin/Symfony-jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/Resources/public/README.md