# Problems With Multiple File Upload In Symfony2

Tags: php, file-upload, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I am making a Symfony2 application which needs to have a multiple image upload option. I have made the single file upload using the cookbook entry: **[How to handle File Uploads with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)** which works fine. I have implemented the **lifecyclecallbacks** for uploading and removing.

Now I need to turn this into a multiple upload system. I have read a few answers from Stack Overflow as well, but nothing seems to work.

Stack Overflow Question:

1. [Multiple file upload with Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736946/multiple-file-upload-with-symfony2)
2. [multiple file upload symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302691/multiple-file-upload-symfony-2)

I have the following code at the moment:

**File** Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    public $file = array();

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }


    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads';
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
            $this->path[] = uniqid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

**FileController**:

```
<?php

namespace Webmuch\ProductBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use Webmuch\ProductBundle\Entity\File;


/**
 * File controller.
 *
 * @Route("/files")
 */
class FileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all File entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="file_upload")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function uploadAction()
    {
        $file = new File();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
            ->add('file','file',array(
                    "attr" => array(
                        "accept" => "image/*",
                        "multiple" => "multiple",
                    )
                ))
            ->getForm()
        ;

        if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($this->getRequest());
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

                $em->persist($file);
                $em->flush();

                $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('file_upload'));
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

and the **upload.html.twig**:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<h1>Upload File</h1>

<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

    {{ form_widget(form.file) }} 

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't know what to do to make this work as a multiple file upload system. I have kept the comments as they are from the tutorials I have followed so I can remember what is doing what.

**UPDATE:**

New Form Code:

```
$images_form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
    ->add('file', 'file', array(
            "attr" => array(
                "multiple" => "multiple",
                "name" => "files[]",
            )
        ))
    ->getForm()
;
```

New Form Twig Code:

```
<form action="{{ path('file_upload') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(images_form) }}>

    {{ form_label(images_form.file) }}
    {{ form_errors(images_form.file) }}
    {{ form_widget(images_form.file, { 'attr': {'name': 'files[]'} }) }}

    {{ form_rest(images_form) }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What isn't working with this at the moment?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I select for example 5 files, only the last file is being uploaded.

Comment: Ah yes - your input control needs to have an individual name - since it doesn't have a name at the moment, it uses a default one for all controls.

Comment: I am unable to add a name to that. Please see my form code I have updated the question. I try to change the name but a default form[file] is coming. And whatever I try to add from the formBuilder is added to the label. Weird!

Comment: _I am unable to add a name to [the form element]_ - in what sense? Do you mean for technical reasons you can't, or that you are trying to do so but it isn't working? If the latter, have you checked the HTML to see what is produced by the Twig template? Also, if the name of `files[]` isn't working, try individual names in a loop (`file_0`, `file_1` etc).

Comment: I tried to add the `name` attribute using the new twig code above but instead of getting added to the widget, it gets added to the label element. I'm not sure how to add it using the for loop, I have a single form element with a `multiple="multiple"`, how can it have multiple name attributes. If you could give a code example, that would be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used Twig. But now you know what the problem is, looking at the Symfony2 docs should make solving it easy `:)`.

Answer (score 15):

This is a known issue [as referenced on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1400).

As they say, you should append `[]` to the `full_name` attribute in your template :

```
{{ form_widget(images_form.file, { 'full_name': images_form.file.get('full_name') ~ '[]' }) }}
```

Comment: In symfony 2.5 you may achieve it using:

`{{ form_widget(images_form.file, {'full_name': images_form.file.vars.full_name ~ '[]' }) }}`

Comment: great! this is the correct answer and it should be marked as valid.

Comment: Thanks for the github issue link. It really helped me out with my validation problem. I added another solution as an answer also, which also works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know if that is possible with the annotation syntax. So I am going to write it in in plain PHP in the controller

```php
$images_form = $this->createFormBuilder($file)
    ->add('file', 'file', array(
        'constraints' => array(
            new NotBlank(), // Makes sure it is filled at all.
            new All(array( // Validates each an every entry in the array that is uploaded with the given constraints.
                'constraints' => array(
                    new File(array(
                        'maxSize' => 6000000
                    )),
                ),
            )),
        ),
        'multiple' => TRUE,
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

This should work perfectly since Symfony 2.4. Before that you would have to put the `multiple` attribute in the `attr` key like you already did.

As I said, you have to to make this work with annotations. It might work but could be less readable if you have to put it all in one line.

Have fun ;)

Comment: regarding the annotations: this is given as an example on the symfony website. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html
`class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\All({
     *     @Assert\NotBlank,
     *     @Assert\Length(min = 5)
     * })
     */
     protected $favoriteColors = array();
}`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem recently, followed the suggestions here, but got an error, because the validator 'file' can't handle arrays.

So I had to write my own validator, which can handle multiple files. For that, I followed [this tutorial from Symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html), copy/pasted the code from validator 'file' in it, encapsulated it with a `foreach` loop and changed the variables as needed.

If you do this, you can use it for `$file` in your entity.