# Multi upload Symfony 2.3 with Dropzone

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, dropzone.js

I tried a new implementation of JQuery library : [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

This library provides a good multi upload interface with drag and drop solution.

It seems that the multi upload system of Symfony isn't easy.

I've this error :

```
Error: Cannot use object of type Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile as array in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Csrf/EventListener/CsrfValidationListener.php line 87
```

My entity File :

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="media__file")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class File
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
public $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $file;

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{

    return __DIR__.'/../../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{

    return 'uploads/files';
}

 /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }


    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

My controller FileController :

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/media/upload")
 * @Template()
 */
public function uploadsAction (){

    $file = new File();

    $form = $this->createForm(new \Tperroin\Bundle\MediaBundle\Form\FileUploadType(), $file);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($file);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tperroin_home_default_index'));
        }
    }

return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

And finally my twig template :

```
<div class="widget-content">

        <form action="{{ url('tperroin_media_file_uploads') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="dropzone">

            <div class="fallback">
                <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

**EDIT :**

FormType :

```
class FileUploadType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('file', 'file');
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'file';
}
}
```

What is wrong with my code ? I know it's a problem with UploadedFile and array but I don't know how to resolve that.

Thank you for all !

**EDIT :**

Maybe this link can help someone, I fail to reproduce this :

[Problems With Multiple File Upload In Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445408/problems-with-multiple-file-upload-in-symfony2)

**EDIT with new uploadAction function :**

```
/**
* @Route("/upload/process", name="upload_media")
*/
   public function uploadAction()
   {
   $request = $this->get('request');
   $files = $request->files;       

   $directory = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web' . $this->getRequest()->getBasePath() . '/files/';

   foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {

       $name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
       $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);

       $upload = new File($name);

       $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

       $em->persist($upload);

       $em->flush();


   }

   return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('tperroin_media_default_index'));
   }
```

Comment: Can you post your FormType? But as I think, all the code expects one file, not multiple.

Comment: Thx ! Of course, see my edit. I tried with the attribute "multiple" but same error...

Comment: You do not render any field - is this normal? At least you need to display a field with a file and csrf token. Also specify `data_class` option in form type

Comment: It's right, see my new template. But I have the same error with this code...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, you don't really use your `FileUploadType` in the Twig template. You create a form manually and set the `action` path to the url you defined in your Controller. The only thing you use from the form view you pass to the template is the `form_enctype`. But like most multi file uploaders, Dropzone seems to forge its own request to upload an Image.

This means you also have to handle the incoming data manually.

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/media/upload")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showUploadAction()
{
    // just show the template
    return [];
}

/**
 * @Route("/admin/media/upload/process", name="upload_media")
 */
public function uploadAction()
{
    $request = $this->get('request');
    $files = $request->files;

    // configuration values
    $directory = //...

    // $file will be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
    foreach ($files as $uploadedFile) {
        // name the resulting file
        $name = //...
        $file = $uploadedFile->move($directory, $name);

        // do something with the actual file
        $this->doSomething($file);
    }

    // return data to the frontend
    return new JsonResponse([]);
}
```

The method `uploadAction` takes the `FileBag` from Symfony's request, iterates over it, and performs your custom logic on the resulting file. Of course you have to handle the storage of the `File` entity by yourself.

Your template should look like this:

```
<form action="{{ path('upload_media') }}" method="post" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Thanks to this question I took notice of the Dropzone uploader and [integrated](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/commit/786efca3939d9d38c78625e6e56cc047daf5e242) support for it in the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle). So you could just use this bundle which simplifies a few steps mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you ! This solution seems work, my files are store in the good directory but I can't persist these images. See my Edit with my uploadAction function. Maybe it's a problem with the UploadFile. Thank you again for your help

Comment: Well you're trying to persist an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`, which is not a Doctrine entity. Instead try to add this file to a new instance of your entity `File` and persist this object instead.

Comment: It works thank you ! I think I understood the concept for files. I tested your bundle and works great !

Answer (score 1):

Symfony requires that every form contains a csrf-token. Your form doesn't contain one so symfony tries to use your "file"-field as a csrf-token and throws the error.
The first step to solve this problem is to render a csrf-token with this snippet in your form-element:

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

Then you have to change your entity that it can handle multiple files. This can be done by implementing a one to many relation (upload (one) to file (many)).

Comment: This would only work for the fallback section of the Dropzone uploader.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony if you have error

```
Error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object
```

Try change

```
$files = $request->files
```

To

```
$files = $request->files->get('file');
```