# Handle multiple files upload with Symfony2 + jQuery FileUpload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, file-upload

Perhaps this question has been asked before several times but I didn't found any answer that helps me. I know also the existence of [OneUpUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) but I think my situation will not work with this plugin (if any knows how to do it, let me know).

I need to upload several files but also I'll have dynamic file inputs as you'll see on the code below. So the only idea I get to do this is `onchange` event from the select build dynamic file fields. This is what I've right now and it works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tipoRecaudo = $('#tipoRecaudo'),
        tipo_recaudo = tipoRecaudo.val(),
        selectedIdsTipoRecaudo = [];

    tipoRecaudo.select2({
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: function () {
                return Routing.generate('obtenerRecaudosTramite');
            },
            data: function (tipo_recaudo) {
                return {
                    filtro: tipo_recaudo
                }
            },
            results: function (data) {
                var myResults = [];
                $.each(data.entities, function (index, item) {
                    if (selectedIdsTipoRecaudo.indexOf(item.id.toString()) === -1) {
                        myResults.push({
                            'id': item.id,
                            'text': item.nombre
                        });
                    }
                });
                return {
                    results: myResults
                };
            }
        },
        formatAjaxError: function () {
            return Translator.trans('mensajes.msgNoConexionServidor', {}, 'AppBundle');
        }
    }).change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val(),
            selectedData = tipoRecaudo.select2("data"),
            baseFilUploadHTML = '<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">' +
                '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>' +
                '<span>Agregar archivos ...</span>' +
                '<input id="fileUpload' + selectedData.id + '" type="file" name="fileUpload' + selectedData.id + '" multiple></span>' +
                '<br><br>' +
                '<div id="progress' + selectedData.id + '" class="progress">' +
                '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="fileUpload' + selectedData.id + '" class="files"></div>' +
                '<br>',
            uploadButton = $('<button/>').addClass('btn btn-primary').prop('disabled', true).text('Procesando...').on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this.off('click').text('Abort').on('click', function () {
                    $this.remove();
                    data.abort();
                });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });

        selectedIdsTipoRecaudo.push(id);

        if (id == 1) {
            // Rif
        } else if (id == 2) {
            // Registro Mercantil
        } else {
            $('#uploadArea').append(baseFilUploadHTML);
        }

        $('#fileUpload' + selectedData.id).fileupload({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: false,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 2000000, // 2 MB
            disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            previewMaxWidth: 100,
            previewMaxHeight: 100,
            previewCrop: true
        }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#fileUpload' + selectedData.id);
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                var node = $('<p/>').append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
                if (!index) {
                    node.append('<br>').append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
                }
                node.appendTo(data.context);
            });
        }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
            var index = data.index,
                file = data.files[index],
                node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
            if (file.preview) {
                node.prepend('<br>').prepend(file.preview);
            }
            if (file.error) {
                node.append('<br>').append($('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error));
            }
            if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
                data.context.find('button').text('Subir').prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
            }
        }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress' + selectedData.id + ' .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                if (file.url) {
                    var link = $('<a>').attr('target', '_blank').prop('href', file.url);
                    $(data.context.children()[index]).wrap(link);
                } else if (file.error) {
                    var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text(file.error);
                    $(data.context.children()[index]).append('<br>').append(error);
                }
            });
        }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index) {
                var error = $('<span class="text-danger"/>').text('Falló la carga de archivos.');
                $(data.context.children()[index]).append('<br>').append(error);
            });
        }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput).parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
    });
});
```

I believe that jQuery-FileUpload handled files upload through Ajax, I'm right? In that case how do I handle files on the Symfony2 controller since for example I need to persist their names and full path to a table column? How you handle this? Any example taking my code as use case?

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701684/multi-upload-symfony-2-3-with-dropzone), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445408/problems-with-multiple-file-upload-in-symfony2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951294/symfony2-file-upload-step-by-step) but is not so helpful as I though. Also official docs for *Handle file uploads with Doctrine* but not clue so far.

Comment: Use `uploadify` jq plugin.I also use this for uploading multiple images in my project. http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/